# mcapply: all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mclapply

The following is my code. I am trying get the list of all the files (~20000) that end with `.idat` and read each file using the function `illuminaio::readIDAT`.

```
library(illuminaio)
library(parallel)
library(data.table)

# number of cores to use
ncores = 8

# this gets all the files with .idat extension ~20000 files
files <- list.files(path = './',
                    pattern = "*.idat",
                    full.names = TRUE)

# function to read the idat file and create a data.table of filename, and two more columns
# write out as csv using fwrite
get.chiptype <- function(x)
{
  idat <- readIDAT(x)
  res <- data.table(filename = x, nSNPs = nrow(idat$Quants), Chip = idat$ChipType)
  fwrite(res, file.path = 'output.csv', append = TRUE)
}

# using mclapply call the function get.chiptype on all 20000 files.
# use 8 cores at a time
mclapply(files, FUN = function(x) get.chiptype(x), mc.cores = ncores)
```

After reading and writing info about 1200 files, I get the following message:

```
Warning message:
In mclapply(files, FUN = function(x) get.chiptype(x), mc.cores = ncores) :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
```

How do I resolve it?

Comment: what are destdir and destfile

Comment: They are just directory and filename where the data.table will be written. I will remove that.

Comment: and you still get errors?

Comment: This may not be the problem, but I'd be wary of appending to a single file from parallel processes. I'm not an expert, but that seems a recipe for trouble. Do you know if they lock the file somehow so they can only write one at a time?

Comment: That is not the problem. Those were just paths to my source and destination files. This is the problem with parallel processing.

Comment: I know for sure that I provided 8 cores and it was writing 8 lines simultaneously. It worked for the first 1200 or so files and then it threw an error. It could also be a problem with reading in the idat files. I will check and get back.

Comment: Perhaps it could have not tried to write simultaneously until the 1201st file. Again, I'm not saying this is the problem, only that parallel processes are notorious for working sometimes and not others due to race conditions like this.

Comment: Whether a try catch block would help?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `mclapply()` in some instances requires you to specify a random number generator that allows for multiple streams of random numbers.
R version 2.14.0 has an implementation of Pierre L'Ecuyer's multiple pseudo-random number generator.

Try adding the following before the `mclapply()` call, with a pre-specified value for '`my.seed`':

```
set.seed( my.seed, kind = "L'Ecuyer-CMRG" );
```