# All scheduled cores encountered errors in user code (unexpected symbol) - but no such code

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-sf, mclapply

/EDIT: My problem has been resolved. It turns out it was indeed an error unrelated to `parallel`.

Hi StackOverflow Community,

today I have a rather odd problem. I have a function which I am calling to run on 8 cores, and it has a parameter called `type`. Running it with `type = "points"` works perfectly, but I am concerned about running it with `type = "lines"`. Even though it follows almost the same code, at some point the script crashes, and all what I get is (after almost 2 days of running!):

```
Warning message: 
In mclapply(cluster_times, the_nt_function, all_trips, ellipses,  :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"
endtime"
Execution halted
```

The first thing I checked is, of course, the code of `the_nt_function`. I provide a summary of the code below.

The important things here, are:

1. The code for type = "points" runs perfectly and gives the expected output
2. The code for type = "lines" seems to run perfectly for nearly 2 days until the error stated above appears
3. The error stated above is inexplicable: there is no 'endtime' or anything in the code below!

`the_nt_function` takes some inputs, and for each row in `times_df` it creates a kind of sample of `dat`. If `type="points"`, it then counts either how many (geographical) points in `dat` are in the `ell` object, using `st_intersection` from `sf`. If `type="lines"`, it basically does the same, but instead of  counting points intersecting with the `ell` object, it counts lines intersecting with the `ell` object.

I let the code run on a high performance cluster (but only using 8 cores). On my computer, it runs fine on 7 cores, at least for a test set of seven entries in the `times_df` object. It does not crash but gives the expected output.

I believe that the error is not in `the_nt_function`. I've googled it and looked for similar problems here on stackoverflow, but the only thing I found so far is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49079935/9665523) (which I am now trying out of desperation).

Do you have any ideas, what this error wants to tell me?

/Edit: I call the function in parallel by:

```
system.time(
    out <- mclapply(cluster_times, the_nt_function, all_trips, ellipses, TRUE, opts$type, mc.cores = cpus)
  )
```

where I give the arguments in correct order.

```
the_nt_function <- function(times_df, dat, sf_object, type) {

  times_df$N_t = as.numeric(NA)
  
  # Here is code that performs some kind of preprocessing and filtering down data, basically creating
  # the data.table dat_filt_spc
    

    for every row in times_df {
      # do some more filtering and end up with a data table called dat_filt_time
      
      if(type == "points"){
      # Convert filtered DT to sf object (using startloc)
        suppressWarnings(
          dat_start_sf <- st_as_sf(
            as.data.frame(dat_filt_time),
            coords = c("startloclon", "startloclat"), 
            crs = 4326
          )
        )
      } else if(type == "lines") {
        suppressWarnings(
          dat_start_sf <- st_as_sf(
            as.data.frame(dat_filt_time),
            crs = 4326
            )
        )
      }
      
      # Intersect startlocs with ellipse
      suppressMessages(
        start_intersect <- st_intersection(dat_start_sf, ell)$tripid
      )
      
      # Convert filtered DT to sf object (using endloc) and filter out trips which are already intersected
      if(type == "points"){
        suppressWarnings(
          dat_end_sf <- st_as_sf(
            as.data.frame(dat_filt_time[!tripid %in% start_intersect]),
            coords = c("endloclon", "endloclat"), 
            crs = 4326
            )
        )
        # Intersect endlocs with ellipse
        suppressMessages(
          end_intersect <- st_intersection(dat_end_sf, ell)$tripid
        )
        # concatenate start and endloc intersections, assess Nt and add to times_df
        trips_intersect <- unique(c(start_intersect, end_intersect))
      } else if(type == "lines"){
        trips_intersect <- start_intersect
      }

      times_df[i, "N_t"] <- length(trips_intersect)
    }
    return(times_df)
  }
}
```

Comment: A good practice here is to write the output of `the_nt_function` to an external file each time it is executed, so that you can retrieve the output of the iterations that don't result in an error.

Comment: at the moment, this will result in ~38,000 single files but it may be worth a shot, thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the code you are running? What you've shared is just defining the `the_nt_function` function. How are you running it?

Comment: Are you sure it's related to `mclapply()`? Maybe it also happens if you replace `mclapply()` with `lapply()`?  If so, that's much easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: @MrFlick: yes, sorry, it's just a mclapply call. I will edit my question!
@HenrikB: tbh I'm not completely sure if it applies to `mclapply()`, since if I'm running it with `mclapply` using only a fraction of the data, I do not encounter the error. But testing it will take too long now, it can't be done in reasonable time without parallelism.
However, I'm now saving single files as function output (as @qdreas suggested), so I'm hoping to get to the problematic parts, soon.